# Eslint Error - Expected to return a value in arrow function

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am correcting some errors which are eslint related and I am getting the following error:

[image]

```
const fileApiLink = process.env.FILE_API_LINK;
const downloadSingleReportAxios = async (id, downloadFile, downloadURL) => {
 const url = fileApiLink.toString();
  await axios
   .post(url, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  data: {
    urlLink: downloadURL,
    fileName: downloadFile
  }
})
.then(response => {
  return response.data;
})
.catch(error => {
  if (error.response) {
    // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
    // that falls out of the range of 2xx
    return console.log(error.response.status);
  } else if (error.request) {
    // The request was made but no response was received
    // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
    // http.ClientRequest in node.js
    return console.log(error.request);
  }
  // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
  console.log('Error', error.message);

  console.log(error.config);
  throw error;
 });
};
```

The code works fine but I am unsure as to where the return statement is required. Can anybody help?

Comment: You've got three arrow functions there. Which one is it asking about?

Comment: Why are you using `await` before the last statement in a function? Why are you mixing `await` and some very chained `then()` and `catch()` calls?

Comment: The first arrow function has no `return` statement. But you're using the returned value in `.then()`

Comment: In general, don't mix `await` and `.then`/`.catch`. Use one or the other.

Comment: it is pointing towards line 21 which is the line under the catch statement

Answer (score 1):

ESlint is telling you that you are not returning anything `async` in that function. You are missing the return while waiting for axios.post

```
return await axios.post(url, ...);
```

It looks like is working because you are calling the API, but the handling of the Promise is actually incorrect.